# dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ParseCrashReporting

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am newbie in parse. My code was working fine before updating cocoapods and after updating it, I am getting this error when I run my application on simulator or on device:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ParseCrashReporting
  Referenced from: /Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AA7147C1-AED6-4E00-BF8B-A4777A1C36CE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/67206EC3-C724-4260-8520-D24E4439493D/....
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AA7147C1-AED6-4E00-BF8B-A4777A1C36CE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/67206EC3-C724-4260-8520-D24E4439493D/...
```

I am working on swift and iOS version is 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fine after giving space between ~> and version number i.e 1.6  in Podfile.

`pod 'ParseCrashReporting', '~> 1.6'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove and then add Parse.framework in Targets -> target_name -> General -> Linked Framework and Libraries